# Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible while using TVP

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i created table valued parameter like this:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ss AS TABLE(ss1 integer);
```

then i wrote my stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[T_TransactionSummary] 
 @locations dbo.ss readonly
as
begin
...............
.............
AND (Location_tbl.Locid IN (select ss1 from @locations))
```

my locid field is integer this locid coming from my listbox.if i select one item 1 locid will come.if i select 2 item 2 locid will come.. I've got a ListBox which populates the @locations parameter (an integer), I took my listbox value like this

```
cnt = LSTlocations.SelectedItems.Count
  Dim dtlist As New DataTable()
    Dim locid As Integer
    If cnt > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To cnt - 1
            dtlist.Columns.Add(locid, GetType(Integer))
            Dim locationanme As String = LSTlocations.SelectedItems(i).ToString
            locid = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", locationanme)
            dtlist.Rows.Add(locid)
        Next
End If
 Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim cmd23 As New SqlCommand("T_TransactionSummary", con.connect)
        cmd23.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Dim tvp1 As SqlParameter = cmd23.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locations", dtlist)
         tvp1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured
        da.SelectCommand = cmd23
        da.Fill(ds)
```

but i am getting error:Trying to pass a table-valued parameter with 2 column(s) where the corresponding user-defined table type requires 1 column(s).

Answer (score 4):

If `LocID` is an integer, then your table type should be:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ss AS TABLE(ss1 INT);
--------------------------------^^^
```

Why on earth are you using `NVARCHAR(5)` here? It doesn't make sense for a variety of reasons.

Also, you need to stop passing your set of locations as a list of integers joined into a comma-separated string. A table-valued parameter is expecting a structured set, like a `DataTable`.

Comment: sir ..in type i changed to int and code i changed to like this:
cmd23.Parameters.Add("@locations", SqlDbType.Int).Value = String.Join(",", list) but getting error:Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.

Comment: @user2878851 I don't even know what that means. But I have only been involved with three of your questions and it is clear that you're ignoring quite a bit of what everybody has been telling you. You keep trying to do the same wrong things over and over again no matter how many times it is explained. You need to help yourself a little here, too.